# Jar of Jars Issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jar

I am creating an API to make entry in my database.(Using Hibernate)

I have made the Classes which maps different table.I exported it to a jar(say jar 1)(containing classes and .hbm.xml files).

Now I am creating APIs(which include jar1) so the end user can update my database.

I have exported the APIs to a jar(say jar2).

Now end user have to include jar2 to access the APIs.But as jar2 uses jar1 I have to provide jar1 to the users as well.

Is there any security issue(database) here as I am providing them with database class file and .hbm.xml files?If yes,how can I avoid it?

I am using java,Hibernate 4 and eclipse(IDE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All "direct-access-to-database" applications (not only for java) have the security issues of that you need to provide to the client workstation with your database login configuration. No way to solve it, except by moving to a three tiered application. In other words, you cannot give an user access to your database without giving him access to your database.

Paliative measures would be setting different database login user / password for each installation (or group of them) and fine tuning your database server security to allow those login only the lowest security privileges needed for your application to run.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any security issue(database) here as I am providing them with database class file and .hbm.xml files?If yes,how can I avoid it?

Yes, you are giving them these details and there is no other way for you to actually avoid it. But at the same time you can have Permission set up for these uers to have Read-Only access.

And more over, if your system needs to be highly secure, why dont you expose these APIs as webserive. You can actually expose the end point and make sure that you return only the required information in another wrapper. This way you can avoid exposing the entities and mapping.